# RegistryManager UpdateTwinAsync doesn't update twins Reported properties

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-iot-hub

I cannot get UpdateTwinAsync to do anything. It does not give errors. It returns the previous reported state.

```
twin.Properties.Reported["data"] = "test";
Twin updatedTwin = await _registryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(twin.DeviceId, twin, twin.ETag);
```

I have tried it every way i can think.

### Console log of the issue:

```
Got Telemetry for IP Address=xxxxxxx for device=josh-test-device
{"$metadata":{"$lastUpdated":"2020-03-24T16:24:16.8339408Z"},"$version":1}
Setting twin.Properties.Reported to telemetry data for IP Address=xxxxxxx for device=josh-test-device
{"$metadata":{"$lastUpdated":"2020-03-24T16:24:16.8339408Z"},"$version":1,"Brand":"AXIS","ProdFullName":"AXIS P1427-LE Network Camera","ProdNbr":"P1427-LE","ProdShortName":"AXIS P1427-LE","ProdType":"Network Camera","ProdVariant":"","WebURL":"http://www.axis.com/"}
TwinUpdate complete for IP Address=xxxxxxx for device=josh-test-device
{"$metadata":{"$lastUpdated":"2020-03-24T16:24:16.8339408Z"},"$version":1}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it doesn't work and I need to use the rest methods? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/twin/updatedevicetwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device twin **reported** properties can not be updated from the service-facing endpoint. See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins).

Comment: I figured it all out after some trial and error. Wrote a blog with my findings. https://medium.com/@admin_86118/navigating-azure-iot-hub-c-sdk-4207d49206ca